# How to convert List of String into LocalDate type Format in Scala

Tags: scala

I have List of String as follow that derived from folder name.

```
List(20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625)
```

I want to convert this whole list of elements into Local Date type format. I have written code in Scala language.Can any one help me?

Comment: what format of Date?

Comment: what have you tried? if i were to convert it, i will loop through each item then  convert it individually

Comment: I want to convert string into LocalDate format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val inputTimes = List(20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625)
val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
val dates = inputTimes.map(date => LocalDate.parse(date.toString, dtf))
dates
```

You can also specify a new locale

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val inputTimes = List(20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625)
val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
val dtfWithLocale = dtf.withLocale(java.util.Locale.US)
val dates = inputTimes.map(date => LocalDate.parse(date.toString, dtfWithLocale))
dates
```

`dates` is the result.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD` format you could do something like this

```
scala> val list = List("20170625", "20170625", "20170625", "20170625", "20170625", "20170625", "20170625", "20170625")
list: List[String] = List(20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625)

scala> import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDate

scala> list.map(input => LocalDate.parse(s"${input.substring(0,4)}-${input.substring(4,6)}-${input.substring(6,8)}"))
res11: List[java.time.LocalDate] = List(2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25)
```

Comment: Hi.. Is this return List that consist of Date type elements?

Comment: I want to convert String type into LocalDate type format. Not  string type

Answer (score 0):

To convert the strings to java.util.Date you can use:

```
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
list.map(df.parse(_))
```

For LocalDate use

```
list.map(LocalDate.parse(_, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")))
```

Comment: I want to convert String type into LocalDate type format.

Answer (score 0):

The split is a crude implementation. However should work

```
  def split(i: Int): LocalDate = {
    val date = i % 100
    val rem = i / 100
    val mon = rem % 100
    val r = rem / 100
    LocalDate.of(r, mon, date)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val l = List(20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625, 20170625)
    val x = l.map(split)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First I wrote the function to convert string into LocalDateTime format as follow

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
private def stringToDateTime(datetime:String): LocalDateTime ={
        val pattern:String="yyyyMMdd"
        LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern))}
```

Then I map values with List of elements as follow

```
def mapDateTime(list:List[String]):List[LocalDateTime] ={
list.map(datetime => stringToDateTime(datetime))}
```

Then I end up with following result

```
List[java.time.LocalDateTime] = List(2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25, 2017-06-25)
```